# Create electron transparent window ontop but clickable below programs

Tags: javascript, window, electron

I have created electron app which on button click shows another window which is 100% height and width and has border around its area. It's also transparent so you can see what is behind this window.

Now I'm wondering if I'm able to make things below clickable or I need to create some kind of hack like this new transparent window make it really small and somehow expand border off this window.

Code responsible for creating new transparent window is:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;
let createTransparentWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

    const mainScreen = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
    createTransparentWindow = () => {
        addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: mainScreen.size.width,
            height: mainScreen.size.height,
            transparent: true,
            frame: false,
            alwaysOnTop: true,
        });
        addWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/transparentWindow.html`)
    };
});


const menuTemplate = [
    {},
    {
        label: 'Record',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'TransparentWindow',
                click() {
                    createTransparentWindow();
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

If I'm able to make apps which are below this window clickable please tell me how if not what kinda trick I need to introduce here?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found answer to my question [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1335). So what you need to browserWindow is:

```
addWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);
addWindow.setFocusable(false);
```

and then you can click through.

Comment: Yes Its working fine